# iOS SDK Write on UIImage draw text

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, uiimage

Code to write text on image:

```
-(UIImage *)addText:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)text1
{
    int w = img.size.width;
    int h = img.size.height; 
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);

    char* text = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 2);

    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 10, 170, text, strlen(text));

    CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];
}
```

And improve with this action:

```
- (IBAction)drawImage:(id)sender {
    NSString *text1 = myTextField.text;
    UIImage *updatedImg = [self addText:myImageView.image text:text1]; 
    [myImageView setImage: updatedImg];
}
```

It working good, after i create a ColorPicker for myTextField, now i can choose the color of my textField.

How can use the same color of myTextField in the first code above?

```
//this is the code color for drawing text    

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 2);

//how can change this to get the color by myTextField?
```

any one can help me please.

thx.

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Hello, please i needed the solution :(

Try to explain better:

In conclusion i will pick the color information by `myTextField.textColor` and report inside the `UIImage` code to do a color text on image.

Thx.

Comment: Can you please rephrase "but i don't know how pass or get the information in UIImage"?  I don't understand the question.

Comment: sure, i will get the color inside myTextField in these code part CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 2);

Comment: finaly i will use my color picker to determinate the color text on image.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: i have one uiimage function for write a text on image right?

Comment: i want take the color information about this text from my uiTextFiled, for example if i change the color of the textField in yellow, i want my uiimage with yellow text, or red blue...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but to set the color of the text from a text field you need to transfer your textField to the addText method and then convert the UIColor of the textField.textColor property to RGB format.

You need to do something like that:

```
-(UIImage *)addText:(UIImage *)img text:(UITextField *)textField
{
    int w = img.size.width;
    int h = img.size.height; 
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);

    char* text = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);

CGColorRef color = [textField.textColor CGColor];

int numComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color);

CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;

if (numComponents == 4)
{
  const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color);
  red = components[0];
  green = components[1];
  blue = components[2];
  alpha = components[3];
}

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, red, green, blue, alpha);

    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 10, 170, text, strlen(text));

    CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];
}
```